# Writing unit tests in Python

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have a task in which i have a csv file having some sample data. The task is to convert the data inside the csv file into other formats like JSON, HTML, YAML etc after applying some data validation rules.

Now i am also supposed to write some unit tests for this in pytest or the unittest module in Python.

My question is how do i actually write the unit tests for this since i am converting them to different JSON/HTML files ? Should i prepare some sample files and then do a comparison with them in my unit tests.

I think only the data validation part in the task can be tested using unittest and not the creation of files in different formats right ?

Any ideas would be immensely helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write your raw data (a file you read or a string representing the file content) and expected result (on a dictionary or string representing the format you want). Then check if the expected result is same as your formatter returned. Try to cover as many cases as you can such as different data types (bool, date, number, string) and missing values. This you do for every format

Comment: why creation of file cannot be tested? It seems everything can be tested with rich python library collection json, csv etc

Comment: If the functions you want to test take file-like objects instead of opening files themselves, you can create `StringIO` objects when you run the tests, rather than having to save a bunch of test files. (Granted, this just moves the test data from separate files to your test suite itself, but the code to generate the data might be more compact than the resulting data itself.)

Comment: @mad_ Having your tests expect to read from, or possibly worse write to, disk is sometimes seen as an unnecessary complication in the testing process.

Comment: I really like making a couple lines as a `StringIO` for testing parsers and conversion stuff - it's tough to keep track of test data files (although I sometimes will do that for more complex data analysis tests that don't test well with small arrays)

Comment: @chepner I know what you are referring to here but sometimes we have to deal with file generation with contents as well. Given the file format, correct parser and OS type we can actually check everything we need. If the task involves a critical info that needs to sit in a file I will actually go into the file to check the contents as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do functional tests, so testing the whole pipeline from a csv file to the end result, but unit tests is about checking that individual steps work.

So for instance, can you read a csv file properly? Does it fail as expected when you don't provide a csv file? Are you able to check each validation unit? Are they failing when they should? Are they passing valid data?

And of course, the result must be tested as well. Starting from a known internal representation, is the resulting json valid? Does it contain all the required data? Same for yaml, HTML. You should not test the formatting, but really what was output and if it's correct.

You should always test that valid data passes and that incorrect doesn't at each step of your work flow.